# I want to take a photo when app in the background? ios

Tags: ios

I want to take a photo  once every 2 minutes but it is essential the app is in the background. for completely legitimate reasons.  Is this possible?

Comment: which one photo you taken?

Comment: photo take from front cam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The only way you can take a photo is through UIImagePickerController(or custom through AVFoundationFramework) which itself requires user action.

Comment: sunil kapoor  please check this link in this case the video if formed.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1TIOIirJXw

Comment: This video is from 2009 and apple has restricted it's ecosystem a lot since then.